# Backup the apt update downloaded files

Tags: debian, apt, backup, live-usb

When I use apt update command it downloaded a 14 mb in that 14 mb how can I backup that so I can put it back to not repeatedly downloading it, because I'm always using live boot.
Edit: Why my questions always getting -1 I didn't want to persuade other to not update their source list! I'm just asking a question...

It doesn't bother me if the source list is outdated, I just downloading dependencies of the app and saving it...

This options is not for me:
Persistent storage in live boot - because I don't want to leave a trace...

Install Debian to quickly solve my problem

Use a virtual machine

I thought the people in stackexchanged is open minded didn't know they just a judgmental that like to down vote others.

Comment: `apt update` will refresh your package lists. Even if you backup it, it will become out of date rather quickly!

Comment: This is exactly what persistent storage is good for. Please explain in your question why you don't want to use it. Why do you need the `apt update`? As Panki already wrote, the result of `apt update` will change when packages get updated in the repositories. If you need to install or update a specific package, you could create a live system that already contains the expected package. Please [edit] your question to answer or to add more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of `apt update` are stored in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. If you back that up, and restore it, and `apt update` will then only changes since the last update.

Comment: Thank you kitt. For answering my question without asking why...